# gwt-query / jquery - option tag inline styling

Tags: java, jquery, html, gwtquery

I've been trying to style html option tags, unsuccessfully. The code I've issued is the following:

```
String htmlString = <something inline styled>;
$("#nombreFuenteLB > option[value^='" + "Helvetica" + "']").replaceWith(htmlString);
```

But there was no good, any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before selecting anything you have to attach the elements to the document,  you should test if the select returns something. Proly your filter doesnt match any element.